# Is there an algorithm to reduce the sides of a Polygon while keeping all Points within the Polygon?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, reduce

I'm trying to reduce a polygon with 4+ vertexes to a polygon with 4 sides to perform perspective transformation later on. I need to find the polygon with 4 sides which contains all the points the original polygon had. Basicly what i want is something like this: 
[image]

The real problem here is that the polygon must only get bigger... if it gets smaller with let's say a polygon approximation algorithm it's not usefull anymore...

EDIT: 
I need the optimal solution, that means that the resulting 4-sided polygon has as little area as possible!

EDIT2: 
What would also work is an convex hull algorithm where I can determine the number of sides the resulting polygon must have!

Comment: Is your polygon convex?

Comment: yes it is! I already filtered all the concave points by doing a convex hull before!

Comment: Links to the similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048024/minimum-area-quadrilateral-algorithm, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11580/minimum-area-bounding-quadrilateral-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to take the bounding box of your polygon, the rectangle defined by the min and max of the x values of your vertices, and the min and max of the y values.

If you need a 4-vertex polygon with smaller area, an idea could be:

- Take the convex hull of your polygon.
- Select one side for deletion, and extend its neighboring sides to the point where they meet. Do this only if they really meet at the end where the deleted side was. Maybe you want to select the side to be deleted by the smallest area that this deletion adds to the polygon (that's the triangle formed by the deleted side and the new intersection point).
- Repeat until only 4 sides are left.

Comment: If I use the bounding box I will lose the information I later need for the Perspective Transformation....

I will try to implement the second algorithm and post feedback once done.

Comment: Okay... for my problem it seems that the extension of the points works fine if i choose the smallest lines to be the ones which are eliminated... I guess that solves my issue :)!